# EF many to many

Tags: entity-framework, mvc, asp.net-mvc

Пишу проект на mvc 4 с entity framework 5.0, использую code first.
Не пойму как правильно должна осуществляться организация many to many.
На сколько я правильно понимаю между двумя таблицами которые требуется связать такой  связью, должна быть еще одна связывающая.

Вопрос: как правильно она должна выглядеть(из каких полей)?

я предполагаю что так: id_табл1, id_табл2. но при генерации кода EF выдает такое предупреждение: "В таблице или представлении(табл1_табл2)  не определен первичный ключ. Ключ был выведен, а определение таблицы или представления было создано в режиме только для чтения." и соответственно при вызове db.SaveChanges(); такое исключение:"Не удалось обновить набор EntitySet "табл1_табл2", поскольку в нем имеется запрос DefiningQuery и отсутствует элемент <InsertFunction> в элементе <ModificationFunctionMapping> для поддержки текущей операции."

надо в связывающую таблицу добавить еще одно поле(первичный ключ)?

Comment: А почему вы явно не укажете ключ для связующей таблицы? Попробуйте атрибут `[Key]`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742359(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Ребят спасибо большое, я разобрался!